# changing attribute state with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand the difference beetwen Jquery .attr() and .prop(). In my website i need to open a popup and inside that I have a form. Now i wonder to know how can I change the state.

If I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="giustificaEntrata" value="1">
```

I want this element checked when I open the popup  - How do I do that?

I also want the `beta` value selected when I open the popup

```
<select name="pippo">
    <option value="vuoto" selected>-</option>
    <option value="beta">beta</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer or a comment, but this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/185672 explains it perfectly. ( try using google/stackoverflow search function first )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr` method changes an element attribute, which is the initial state. The `prop` value changes the element property, which is the current state.

To set the checked state, use the `prop` method:

```
$('input[name=giustificaEntrata]').prop('checked', true);'
```

To select an option, use the `val` method:

```
$('select[name=pippo]').val('beta');
```

Comment: what is the difference beetwhen: $('select[name=pippo]').val('beta') and $('select[name=pippo]').eq(1).prop('selected',true)

Comment: @EmanueleUgo: Well, one works, the other one not. :) It would be `$('select[name=pippo] option').eq(1).prop('selected',true);` for the second one to work. For a `select` without the `multiple` attribute, the result is the same. The difference is only how it's done. The result of `$('select[name=pippo] option')` is a jQuery object with all the option elements in the select, and you don't need all of them so that's a wasteful way to select one option.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox `checked` property basically has two states. checked - true & checked - false.

From [prop documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), 
*According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute.*

Also, *The checked **attribute** value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked **property** does.*

```
$('[name="giustificaEntrata"]').prop('checked',true);
```